# Math on values inside an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum

I was looking for some way to make calculations on values inside array. I know that I can sum the values, sort it or returs max/min. But I am novice and i do not find anything about harder math. I have formula:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mduac.jpg
(can't attach images yet...)

And I have an array [somex, somey, somex, somey,somex, somey, ....] Is it possible to calculate the thing like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need some logic like this:

```
int current=0 ,previous=0,yoursum=0;
for(i=0;i<no. of elements in array;i++)
{

 current=arr[i];
 else
 {
  yoursum+=previous-current;
  previous=current;
  }
}
```

Comment: Has that else got a missing if?